# Missing EventToCommand behaviour in mvvmlight for Windows 8 - Work Around?

Tags: c#, windows-8, mvvm-light, winrt-xaml

Question says it all really :)

I'm writing a Windows 8 app in XAML/C# using MVVM Light and I've noticed the EventToCommand feature hasn't been implemented yet.

Are there any work arounds for this that anybody can suggest?

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the EventToCommand behavior written by LocalJoost which uses Reactive Extensions:
http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.be/2012/07/a-winrt-behavior-to-mimic-eventtocommand.html

Comment: Thanks! this did the job nicely

Answer (score 14):

You can now accomplish what EventToCommand used to do using the [Behaviors SDK (XAML) for Visual Studio 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn457340.aspx), without using other tools, (@localJoost 's [WinRTBehaviors](http://winrtbehaviors.codeplex.com/) is deprecated now after it helped all of us those times) :

[image]

An example of its use would be as follows :

```
<Slider x:Name="Sl_VolumeSilder">
        <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="ValueChanged">
                <Core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnSliderValueChangedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=Sl_VolumeSilder, Path=Value}"/>
            </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Slider>
```

Where Interactivity and Core are referenced :

```
xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:Core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
```

Comment: Quick comment, this apparently only works if you're targeting Windows 8.1. Requirement of VS 2013 hints at this but documentation isn't too clear.

Comment: Yes that's correct, since VS2013 creates only Windows8.1 apps, still you can create Windows8 apps in VS2012 and open them later in VS2013

Answer (score 2):

I just did a blog post on that exact issue see my entry here.

http://blog.tattoocoder.com/2012/08/getting-started-w-windows-8-mvvm-light.html

Uses WinRTBehaviors and Win8nl from @localJoost