# method in viewmodel not being called/reached in MVVM - (cannot fetch the value of field)

Tags: wpf, mvvm

** if there is an answered question to such question, please let me know then I will delete it. I didn't find or maybe I am not using the right keywords. I will be happy to remove it just post me the URL.

Edit: During debugging I noticed this:

> insertCommand = Cannot fetch the value of field 'insertCommand'
>   because information about the containing class is unavailable.

I'm writing a very simple MVVM project where I'm biding a button to a method in ViewModel.

I have created a command object in ViewModel as

```
private ICommamand InsertCommand;
```

Then

```
    public ICommand insertCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.insertCommand == null)
                this.insertCommand = new RelayCommand(() => this.AddStudent(), () => this.CanAddStudent());

            return this.insertCommand;
        }
    }
```

Also, have a mentod as

```
    private void AddStudent()
    {
        //do something here

    }
```

Of course by default CanAddStudent is return true and also in the View I have

```
 <Button x:Name="btnShow" Content="Show" Command="{Binding InsertCommand}" ....
```

Yet, it doesn't get triggered. What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you instantiated the command (e..g = new InsertCommand();)

Comment: private ICommamand InsertCommand; change to:
ICommand InsertCommand = new InsertCommand();

Comment: Actually I've just noticed you are instantiating the command in the getter.

Comment: yes I have done it as `this.insertCommand = new RelayCommand(() => this.AddStudent(), () => this.CanAddStudent());`

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in the getter, is it actually being called?

Comment: I did and that had made me think something is not right with the button on UI. In fact, I created a method in MainWindows.xaml code behind and yet is not getting there.

Comment: I would guess something is wrong with your binding, add find out what the data context is of the button, if it is not calling the getter it probably isn't bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the public Property you have exposed is named "insertCommand", and you're binding to "InsertCommand", which you have made private.

Change your binding to `<Button x:Name="btnShow" Content="Show" Command="{Binding insertCommand}" />`

Comment: changed it to   `<Button x:Name="btnShow" Content="Show" Command="{Binding insertCommand}" Height="40" Width="70" Grid.Row="1" />`  yet doesn't bind it.

Comment: Just use snoop : http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/87261
to see what is wrong with your binding.

Comment: Ok after running snoop I noticed DataContext is empty so I guess this is the issue. now question is where can I initialize it? In the code before I had `DataContext={binding}` like  <Button DataBinding={Binding} ... /> but was not doing anything meaningful for me so I removed it.

Answer (score 1):

`Command` does not work out of the box in win8 RT. You have to go through behaviors.

All of this is very well explained [here](http://blog.tattoocoder.com/2012/08/getting-started-w-windows-8-mvvm-light.html) for example.

And you can also refer to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020559/missing-eventtocommand-behaviour-in-mvvmlight-for-windows-8-work-around) if you need a more involved answer.

Comment: I'm using Windows 8 so something gone bad in my code.   Thank you

Comment: I am not using Light MVVM so ... not sure if that is the way to go for this case. thanks though

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the ViewModel constructor I had written. I was passing a value to constructor where it was not initialized properly and it was not accessible.

While debugging the code and after placing few Add Watches noticed this message:

*insertCommand = Cannot fetch the value of field 'insertCommand' because information about the containing class is unavailable.*

I like to thank nzic for recommending of snoop to debug the xaml.

Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. Is the problem solved?
If not, what is the type of control that hosts your button and does it's data context point to your ViewModel?