# Cannot fetch the value of field '' because information about the containing class is unavailable

Tags: c#, sql-server

The exact site is running on my IIS web server. I downloaded the whole source code from the site and tried to run it on my VS 2013 for web. All the page runs fine, but when I tried to submit data into database using the form inside the site, it returns a lot of this error `"Cannot fetch the value of field '' because information about the containing class is unavailable"`

[image: error]

Please take a look at the attached image to see the problem I'm having. This exact form is working without any problem on the site. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe have a look at ["*method in viewmodel not being called/reached in MVVM - (cannot fetch the value of field)*"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14946760/1364007). I have the same problem but it matters less to me so I have added [[DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerbrowsableattribute)] to the member so it's not shown.